# Filter one array by type, depending other

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I need to create two results from body_Task depending on the   `Header_Tasks.type`

Header_Tasks

```
[
  {"_id":"AAA54" "title":"task 1" "type":1},
  {"_id":"bbb45" "title":"task 2" "type":2},
  {"_id":"ccc56" "title":"task 3" "type":1},
  {"_id":"xxx98" "title":"task 4" "type":2},
]
```

I have been created it depending on Header_Tasks,
its name is body_taks, I save the data (header, body) in my database because it has other functions on my project

body_taks

```
{
  "AAA54":10,
  "AAA54|max":10,
  "bbb45":07,
  "bbb45|max":20,
  "ccc56":05,
  "ccc56|max":30,
  "xxx98":03,
  "xxx98|max":15,
}
```

I wish it, two results depending on Header_Tasks.type

type 1

```
{
  "AAA54":10,
  "AAA54|max":10,
  "ccc56":05,
  "ccc56|max":30,
}
```

type 2

```
{
  "bbb45":07,
  "bbb45|max":20,
  "xxx98":03,
  "xxx98|max":15,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a fairly standard 'group by' first creating a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to look up types against, then grouping by type in the result object.

```js
const headerTasks = [{ _id: "AAA54", title: "task 1", type: 1 }, { _id: "bbb45", title: "task 2", type: 2 }, { _id: "ccc56", title: "task 3", type: 1 }, { _id: "xxx98", title: "task 4", type: 2 },];
const bodyTasks = { AAA54: 10, "AAA54|max": 10, bbb45: "07", "bbb45|max": 20, ccc56: "05", "ccc56|max": 30, xxx98: "03", "xxx98|max": 15, };

const typeMap = new Map(headerTasks.map((t) => [t._id, t.type]));

const result = {};

for (const key in bodyTasks) {
    const id = key.includes("|") ? key.slice(0, key.indexOf("|")) : key;
    const t = typeMap.get(id);
    if (t !== undefined) {
        result[`type${t}`] ??= {};
        result[`type${t}`][key] = bodyTasks[key];
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

*Note: I have converted the numbers prefaced with `0` to strings as [octal literals] are not allowed in strict mode and I wasn't sure if you intended them as octals.*